# Flask thorwing 400 at POST json endpoint

Tags: flask, curl, http-status-code-400

One of my endpoints in a flask app is returning 400 for every request and I have absolutely no idea why.

Can anyone help me understand the issue? Also, is there any tool to debug 400 messages in flask?

This is the request cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://vegaz.bet/api/tibiacoin/confirmation' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token_here' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: session_cookie_here' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": "620ef8bafb429c69efca3546",
    "amount": 25,
    "status": "OK",
    "character": "Denis Santos"
}'
```

This is the endpoint:

```
@api_blueprint.route("/tibiacoin/confirmation", methods=["POST"])
def tibicoin_withdrawal_confirmation():
    validate headers
    auth_token = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    if auth_token != "Bearer " + os.environ["TOKEN"]:
        response_dict = {"status": False}
        return jsonify(response_dict)

    content = request.get_json()
    withdrawal_id = content["id"]
    withdrawal_status = content["status"]

    if withdrawal_status == "OK":
        withdrawal_object = TibiaWithdrawal.objects(pk=withdrawal_id)[0]
        withdrawal_object.is_processed = True
        withdrawal_object.save()

    response_dict = {"status": True}
    return jsonify(response_dict)
```

Comment: Why didn't you use FlaskHTTPAuth

Comment: Still in development phase, was a quick way to test something. Do you believe this to be the source of error?

Comment: I  just think it is much simpler to use FlaskHTTPAuth. I do not know how you implemented your auth.I cannot tell the source of the error for sure . So, what do you get when you try to debug the endpoint?

Comment: I'll sure think about it, but it actually has nothing to do with the problem, just ran some tests and even excluding auth the endpoint always returns 400

Comment: What about printing and dumping random stuff from the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, turns out I was using CRSF protection from flask-WTForms. Since this specific endpoint was an API endpoint, I needed to remove the protection by adding the following code to the view:

```
from app import csrf

@api_blueprint.route("/tibiacoin/confirmation", methods=["POST"])
@csrf.exempt
def tibicoin_withdrawal_confirmation():
 ...
```